# DataReader causing SQL Server to leak available memory

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ado.net

I have a PowerShell script that's reading data from a local SQL Server Express 2014 database and writing it to a CSV file. It works fine, but it's using up almost the entire pool of available memory from SQL Server, and **not releasing it when the script is finished running**. Even calling GC.Collect() doesn't release the memory; I have to restart the SQL Server service to get it back.

Here's the relevant portion of the script, where I've determined the leak is occurring:

```
try {
    $sqlConn = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($sqlConnString);
    $sqlConn.Open();

    $sqlCmd = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand;
    $sqlCmd.Connection = $sqlConn;
    $sqlCmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::Text;
    $sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM $exportReadings";

    #Write contents to a CSV file
    $line = New-Object -TypeName System.Text.StringBuilder;
    $out = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.StreamWriter -ArgumentList $csvFile, $false;
    $out.WriteLine("HEADER_ROW");        
    $reader = $sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
    $cols = $reader.VisibleFieldCount;
    while ($reader.Read()) {
        $line.Clear();
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $cols; $i++) {
            $val = $reader.GetValue($i);
            if ($val -like "*$delimiter*") {
                $line.Append('"').Append($val).Append('"');
            }
            else {
                $line.Append($val);
            }

            if ($i -ne ($cols - 1)) {
                $line.Append($delimiter);
            }
        }
        $out.WriteLine($line.ToString());
    }
}
catch {
    throw;
}
finally {
    if ($reader) { $reader.Dispose(); }
    if ($out) {
        $out.Close();
        $out.Dispose();
    }
    $sqlCmd.Dispose();
    $sqlConn.Dispose();
}
```

If I query memory usage on SQL Server before running the script (I'm using `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_query_resource_semaphores`), I get `available_memory_kb) of about 750K. Afterwards, it's around 150K, even once the script has terminated.

I've tried to release every resource I can, but I must be missing something. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is a powershell issue at all. If you're seeing that SQL server's memory has increased, then this normal. SQL server will use all the memory it can, for caching. That memory will be released if something else in the system needs it, but the idea is that if possible it would bring every database into memory and leave it there so that future accesses are very fast.

[A Sysadmin’s Guide to Microsoft SQL Server Memory](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/09/sysadmins-guide-microsoft-sql-server-memory/)

Comment: Sorry, I tried to do my best to make my question clear, but it's not an increase in the system memory SQL Server is using. It's a *decrease* in the memory available to SQL Server internally.

Comment: Is this just an observation or is it causing an actual problem? The fact that you have to restart the SQL server service supports the idea that this issue lies in SQL server itself.

Comment: It's causing a problem. Once the memory goes missing, it isn't used for other queries, which are just locking up and spinning endlessly because the server doesn't have the resources to complete them. So this isn't a scenario where the memory just hasn't been reclaimed because it hasn't been needed yet.